# How to get Dan Wahlin AngularJS Demos working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and found this fantastic demo by Dan Wahlin. I downloaded the files but can't run them locally. Anyone had this isue. I tried changing the path to the DemoPartials folder like it suggested in the Readme file but no luck. 
I don't have visual studio and am just using textMate on a mac.

The demo files are this url : http://tinyurl.com/AngularJSDemos

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM

**Updated note:**

Thanks *thescientist* for spotting the localhost bit. 
For anyone trying to run this on a mac mountain lion. here is the drill

- sudo apachectl start
- Dump the folder AngularJSDemos into your /Library/WebServer/Documents/
- Then open the app folder and the app.js file.
- add '/AngularJSDemos' to all the start of the templateUrl

You should be good to go.

Comment: so what is happening then?  Doesn't run is pretty vague.  It's a 60m video, which part are you stuck on?

Comment: If you read the post it says I downloaded the files and that's what I'm trying to run. When I open CustomerManagementApp.html in a browser the partials are not loading. I'm not referring to the 60 minute video.

Comment: I did read your post.  And since you posted the video, I assumed it was relevant.  Are you checking in your console for errors?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/app/partials/customers.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=i9MHigUZKEM#t=826), he is running his application on top of a web server.

This could either be Apache or nodejs, but it doesn't really matter which one you use.  But that's essentially what the error message is trying to tell you.  You need to be loading all assets over `http://`

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2012 solution is designed to run with IIS Express. To open it follow these steps:

1. Start Visual Studio 2012
2. Select File --> Open Website and select the AngularJSDemos folder
3. Right-click on the website project and select Use IIS Express from the menu

You should be all set.

If you don't want to use Visual Studio you can still run everything but you'd possibly need
to update the urlBase path in DemoList.html since it expects DemoPartials to be off the root
of whatever site you run.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to debug the Website through Visual Studio 2012, I was getting the following error:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

After making the following changes I was able to run the website through Visual Studio 2012

1)  Right-click on the website project
2)  Select **Property Pages**
3)  In **Start Options** change from the **Use current page** radio button to **Specific page** and select **CustomerManagementApp.html**

Keeping the **Use current page** and selecting the **CustomerManagementApp.html** in the Visual Studio solution also works.